# Radius of Circumcircle formed by triangle made of Pythagorean triplet

Tags: number-theory, pythagorean-triples

My book on number theory says that Radius of Circumcircle formed by triangle made of Pythagorean triplet cannot be an Integer which seems wrong to me.

Considering a triangle with sides 6,8,10, the radius would obviously be a 5 which is a integer. Am I missing something or is the book wrong?

It says since X is a even number. Why does X have to be Even? Is it just a copyright trap?

[image: The "concept"]

Comment: Yeah, but the book doesn't say anywhere that this is true only for even X. It just says since X is even

Comment: Presumably they are speaking of primitive triples.

Comment: Read the line written just after the word concept

Comment: Yes.  Easy to prove that the hypotenuse of such a thing is always odd.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Unnecessary ambiguity is unnecessary

Comment: It should say $primitive$ Pyth, triplet, that is, $a^2+b^2=c^2$ where $a,b,c$ have no common divisor greater than $1$, which means there are co-prime $m,n\in \Bbb N$, not both odd, with $c=m^2+n^2$ and $\{a,b\}=\{m^2-n^2, 2mn\}.$  Since one of $m,n$ is even and one is odd, $ c$ is odd. The mid-point of the hypotenuse of a right $\triangle$ is its circumcenter so the circumradius is $c/2.$

Comment: I recall a professor telling of a female student-teacher  talking for 1/2 an hour to  an all-boys high-school class about the $circumcised$ circle of a $\triangle.$....... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps they mean *primitive* Pythagorean triples.  Those *do* have to have odd hypotenuses.  All primitive Pythagorean triples (and some non-primitive ones) can be generated via the pattern $\{u^2-v^2, 2uv, u^2+v^2\}$, where $u$ and $v$ are positive integers, and $u^2+v^2$ is the hypotenuse.

Note that the leg $2uv$ is clearly even.  Now suppose the hypotenuse $u^2+v^2$ were also even; then $u^2-v^2$ would have to be even as well.  But then all three sides would be even, and the triple would not be primitive.

Their example is just that—an example.  Not all primitive triples are of the form they give.  For instance, $5$-$12$-$13$ clearly isn't.